# Omnipay, Expresso Store and 3D Secure

Tags: payment-gateway, expressionengine, omnipay, expresso-store

I'm having trouble implementing a new payment gateway for Expresso Store using the Omnipay library.

The main issue is that I can access credit card related details during the PurchaseRequest by calling $this->getCard()->getName() & $this->getCard()->getNumber() - I post these and other details off to the payment gateway which checks the 3DSecure status of the card prompts the user for an OTP if the card is enrolled for 3DSecure.

The gateway then posts back to my module for the next leg of processing at which time I implement the CompleteAuthoriseRequest.

But I no longer have access to the CardName or CardNumber - the methods $this->getCard()->getName() & $this->getCard()->getNumber() return FALSE and even ExpressionEngine sessionCache doesn't work.

Does Omnipay have some built in session caching that I can use to persist these values between calls ? I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: You might get better traction if you ask on the EE specific site http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com